# Different "Preferred Networks" for different Network "Location"

Tags: network, wifi

The question is: can I have different "Preferred Networks" when switching from one to another Network "Location"?

This issue has been discussed before at [Ask Different: Can't I use different WiFi networks for different Locations?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/41464/cant-i-use-different-wifi-networks-for-different-locations). However, I do not like a solution that ought to use some external App.

I would appreciate any comment! Thanks!

Comment: It supposed to do just that. So what is not working ?

Comment: All WiFis are appearing in all Locations :-(

Comment: You have to name them something other then just WiFi :) Like WiFi Home, WiFi Friend,,,,,Click on the Gear box and rename service according to the location!

Comment: @Ruskes however you name the location or the interface there is a leak between all the Wi-Fi settings.

Answer (score -1):

Each of your Locations will show WiFi.

To differentiate by location you have to rename them.

To do that click on the Gear box icon at the bottom of the location screen and choose rename service.

Now you can get creative in naming the service to your liking in each of the Locations. The WiFi function will remain.

Comment: Your approach doesn't seem to do what I *think* the OP asked. I began with a single location: `Automatic`. From there I create a New Location (NEWLOCATION). In the NEWLOCATION Network panel, I re-name the WiFi to WiFi-NEWLOCATION. I `Apply` these changes, then use the `Advanced...` menu to edit the Preferred Networks for Wi-Fi-NEWLOCATION. I select `OK`, & `Apply` again. I'm now connected to the actual WiFi service in my actual location. But when I return to `Automatic` by selecting and `Apply`ing, I find the changes I made to Wi-Fi-NEWLOCATION have also been applied to (the default) Wi-Fi.

Comment: This suggested solution doesn't work wirh Yosemite, El Capitan, Sierra and High Sierra. Is it working with any more recent version?